# Mongoose populate a virtual instead of the entire Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to `.populate` a specific Model, but it seems it ignores the second `select` command if it is a **virtual**...

```
// This won't work - it just returns the _id meaning it didn't populate
.populate({ path: 'user', select: 'post' }) // Post is a : virtual('post')
.populate('user', 'post') // Also doesn't work

// If I manually select all the fields the virtual does, that works of course
.populate({ path: 'user', select: '_id name image type' })
```

Here's the virtual I'm creating on the User object

```
// Here's the relating parts of the Model

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    type: {},
    image : String
});

// Here's the virtual
UserSchema
.virtual('post')
.get(function () {
    return {
        '_id' : this._id,
        'name' : this.name,
        'type' : this.type,
        'image' : this.image
    };
});
```

I must be missing something... Read the documentation and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose is not promising to populate virtuals with select attribtue also docs says nothing. It seems , works manually generally.

You can create constant variables on `UserScheme` which will be suitable for situation instead of using virtual. It can return select's string.

```
UserScheme.getPostFields = "_id name image type"; // under UserScheme
// pass on select method
.populate({ path: 'user', select: UserScheme.getPostFields });
```

This method can be strange, but also you can change this situation in a dynamic way if you need.

By the way there is a suitable on npm [mongoose-populate-virtuals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-populate-virtuals) for this situation.

Comment: Thank you! And yes that's what I realized I might have to do... I'll check out populate-virtuals plugin as well. Appreciate your help